# no envia ningun tipo de peticion al borrar registro por ajax (jquery) y laravel

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel-5

Llevo unos dias intentando resolver esto y no lo consigo,
Estoy haciendo la logica para eliminar por ajax registros pero no me funciona, si me voy al apartado del firefox para desarrolladores, en la pestaña red, una vez hago la peticion, no hace nada, no envia ningun tipo de peticion POST, he probado si esta bien enlazado y efectivamente funciona el jquery en esa pagina , pero con ajax no acaba de funcionar, pienso que puede ser de dos cosas, una es de la ruta

```
url: 'http://localhost/ficheros/laravel_escuelait/public/admin/categorias/'+valorIdCategoria,
```

que funciona perfectamente, es decir valorIdCategoria coge el valor que tiene que coger y es la ruta que a la que hay que enviar en las peticiones "delete".

El otro factor que pienso que puede fallar son los datos, es decir

```
data: {'_method':'DELETE','id': valorIdCategoria},
```

Si lo pruebo asi,  errorThrown del metodo fail me arroja esto

`error 500 _ Internal Server Error`

sin embargo si lo pongo asi

```
data: {id: valorIdCategoria}
```

, o asi

```
data: {'id': valorIdCategoria},
```

me arroja este error

```
error 405 _ Method Not Allowed
```

Pongo el resto del codigo

CONTROLADOR CATEGORIAS (NO LLEGA NUNCA AL CONTROLADOR)

```
   public function destroy($id,Request $request)
    {

        if($request->ajax()):
                $delCat = \App\modelos\categoria::find($request->$id);
                $delCat->delete();
        endif;

        return redirect()->to('/admin/categorias');

    }
```

CODIGO DE LA VISTA

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover" id="listadopost">
                        <thead>

                            <tr class="text-uppercase">

                                <th>Categorias</th>
                                <th>Editar</th>
                                <th>Eliminar</th>

                            </tr>

                        </thead>
                        <tbody>

                            @foreach($listacat as $cat)
                            <tr>

                                <td class="text-capitalize nombrecatx">{{$cat->nombrecat}}</td>


                                <td><a href="{{route('admin.categorias.edit',array($cat->id))}}" class="btn btn-warning"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span></a></td>
                                <td>


                                    {!! Form::open(array('route' =>array('admin.categorias.destroy',$cat->id),'method'=>'DELETE')) !!}
                                    {!! Form::hidden('catid', $cat->id, []) !!}
                                    <input type="submit"  class="btn btn-danger glyphicon glyphicon-trash eliminarcategoria" value ="DEL" >
                                    {!! Form::close() !!}
                                </td>
                            </tr>

                        @endforeach
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
```

LAS RUTAS

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin','middleware' => 'auth'], function() {

    Route::resource('categorias','categoriaController');

});
```

LA FUNCION AJAX, CARGADA EN LA VISTA

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.eliminarcategoria',this).click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();


    var fila = $(this).parents('tr');
    var valorIdCategoria = fila.find('input[name="catid"]').val();
    var valorCategoria = String(fila.find('td.nombrecatx').text()); 
    var color = fila.css({'background-color':'maroon',
                        'font-size':'1.5em',
                        'color':'white',

                        });



                    $.ajax({
                                url: 'http://localhost/ficheros/laravel_escuelait/public/admin/categorias/'+valorIdCategoria,
                                method: 'POST',
                                dataType: 'json',
                                //data: {'id': valorIdCategoria},
                                data: {'_method':'DELETE','id': valorIdCategoria},
                                headers: { 'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="_token"]').attr('content') },
                            })
                            .done(function(data) {
                                console.log("success");

                            $('#panelposts').before(notificacion('success','El registro se ha eliminado correctamente desde ajax'));
                            })
                            .fail(function(ex, errorThrown) {
                                console.log("error "+ex.status+' _ '+errorThrown);
                                $('#panelposts').before(notificacion('danger','ERROR FATAL'+errorThrown));
                            })
                            .always(function() {
                                console.log("complete");
                            });

    })
});
```

No se muy bien cual es el motivo por el que no manda ninguna clase de peticion, en otros proyectos que he hecho usando ajax aunque me podia dar algun tipo de error al menos mandaba la peticion POST, erronea eso si, pero la mandaba.

¿Alguna idea de que puede ser?

Comment: Creo que hay algo de redundancia en la información que envias, más tarde te elaboro una forma un poco distinta de hacer este procedimiento.

Answer (score 1):

Es porque en tu controlador tienes

```
public function destroy($id,Request $request)
{

    if($request->ajax()):
            $delCat = \App\modelos\categoria::find($request->$id);
            $delCat->delete();
    endif;

    return redirect()->to('/admin/categorias');

}
```

cuando en realidad es

```
public function destroy(Request $request, $id)
{

    if($request->ajax()):
            $delCat = \App\modelos\categoria::find($request->$id);
            $delCat->delete();
    endif;

    return redirect()->to('/admin/categorias');

}
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/controllers#dependency-injection-and-controllers

Answer (score 0):

Creo que esta entrando en conflicto el formulario y la función ajax.
Desde mi punto de vista no te haría falta crear el formulario, yo haría algo así:

```
<input type="hidden" name='catid' value="{{ $cat->id }}" >
<input type="button" class="btn btn-danger glyphicon glyphicon-trash eliminarcategoria" value ="DEL" >
```

Answer (score 0):

Debes siempre desarrollar mirando los logs para tener todo controlado en caso de falla. Las fallas 500 por lo general es un error antes o durante la ejecución de Laravel, que no llegan al log del framework, por lo que si lo estás mirando, no verás el fallo.

Sugerencia, revisa siempre en este orden:

1) **access.log de apache**, para saber si ingresó a tu servidor web, con qué parámetros, si haciendo POST o GET, etc.

2) **error.log de apache**, ahí verás el fallo a nivel del servidor web, muchas veces verás un error ahí y no llegará a verse en el log de laravel.

3) **php_errors.log**, si tienes configurado para enviar los errores desde tu php.ini

4) proyecto/storage/logs/laravel.log, el log de tu proyecto que genera Laravel.

Sobre tus errores concretos:

1. **Error 500**: puede ser un fallo de sintaxis, y no lo verás en el log de laravel, por lo que tienes que revisar los logs anteriores.
2. **Error 405**: estás intentando acceder a una ruta de una forma distinta a cómo la definiste en routes de laravel. Ya donde definas que la ruta es post y en realidad el ajax venga por get, te fallará. Tiene que coincidir exactamente lo definido con lo que estás haciendo, revisa el log de access de apache y verás si ingresa y con qué método (get o post).

Comment: Veo que has escrito la misma respuesta en dos preguntas similares, y en ninguna estás respondiendo a la pregunta, de hecho parecen más comentarios lo que pones.